# How to create an installer for C++ program without exposing key files for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, security, advanced-installer

I have created an application using qt creator which creates an .exe file. At runtime the .exe file uses dlls and a few tensorflow graphs. I tried using advanced installer for this and all my key tensorflow graphs are exposed in the directory in which the installer unloads the files. This is a problem because I need to send it to the customer and need all these files hidden. I wanted to know if there is a way to hide these files while creating the installer.

Comment: Not really an installer problem then if your application actually needs those files installed. Maybe you should consider packaging your graphs into an encrypted container and have your application decrypt than data on the fly?

Comment: Using the Files and Folders section in Advanced Installer if you double click on a file you will get exposed the properties you can set for file at install time. One of those properties is the "Hidden" attribute, if this is what you are looking for.